# i want do modify htmlelement from string in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an String with htmlcode, I want do insert data in this element and add attributes like src for img. But only I can modify from html-document but i want only to modify in this element I write an example here. This doesn't work but it shows what i mean. 
I tried

```
var element = $('<form method="post" action="">
    <button value="all" type="submit">Get All Wines!</button>
    <button value="red" type="submit">Get Red Wines!</button>
    <button value="white" type="submit">Get White Wines!</button>
 </form>
 <div class="test">
 </div>');
            element.find('div.test').html('test');
```

if i make this:

```
$('div.test').append('hey');
```

I don't want to modify in my html file but i want only modify this generate element from string

Comment: post your html, the code you posted doesn't really make sense

Comment: $('.test').text('Hey This is some text in this element this was super easy if you just look at the jquery documentation');   <-- try that.

Comment: This question would be better if you included a small sample of HTML and give us a better idea of exactly what you are attempting. Your jQuery code is off on your second example and it seems like you just want to append new elements onto the DOM and maybe change a few HTML attributes? But I am just guessing here...

Comment: So a bunch of things wrong here. The way you are selecting elements with jquery is wrong and instead of .html you want .text

Comment: sry is it ok so? i updated it

Comment: I'm not clear on what this actually means. Can you say it another way? "it want to modify in my html file but i want only modify this generate element from string"

Comment: i don't want to modify in my html file sry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/puxaga/1/edit?js,console,output)**

Use `closest()` for finding elements

```
    var element = $('<form method="post" action="">   <button value="all" type="submit">Get All Wines!</button> <button value="red" type="submit">Get Red Wines!</button> <button value="white" type="submit">Get White Wines!</button> 

</form> <div class="test" id="rias"> HI </div>');

    element.closest('.test').html("Rias");

    $("body").append(element);
```

Comment: TypeError: element.closest is not a function

Comment: It's working in the demo. May be wrap with $(element).closest("div.test").html("rias")

Comment: this was right but then it didn't modify something, is it important that i i want to do this in an .done().. function from ajax request ?

Comment: If you are receiving that HTML string from ajax in the sense you need to do it inside the done() function.

Comment: ok now it works i did it with appendTo and wrote $(element).appendTo("body"); but i had to write $($(element)).appendTo("body");  thanks :)